# How to set advanced data grid column from a xternal xml?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, advanceddatagrid

I have a xml file

```
<Column id="first name" headerLabel="first name" dataField="first name" />
<Column id="regionName" headerLabel="Region" dataField="region_name" />" 
<Column id="lastname" headerLabel="last_name" dataField="last_name"/>
```

I want this column name to be assigned to my data grid as i am succesfull in picking up  data from a back end and save in a variable now i just want to display it in my advanced data grid can any body guide me how to do that with a written example?

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid 
  id="list"
  dataProvider="{data}"                      
  columns = ?/>
```

I  am using this code supoose my xml file name is in assets/config/rumpy.xml from which i want to retrieve column name using header field.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to convert this XML to a XMLList and add columns to the data grid while iterating through its elements.

By default you should determine an empty set of data grid columns. In my example if you don't do it, you will get two times more columns, because the grid can define columns automatically according to the data provider's structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        private var columnList:XMLList;

        [Bindable]private var data:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {first_name:"John",     last_name:"Busch",  region_name:"CA"},
            {first_name:"Mike",     last_name:"Harris", region_name:"DC"},
            {first_name:"Linda",    last_name:"Brucks", region_name:"CA"}]);

        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            loadXML();
        }

        private function loadXML():void
        {
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLComplete);
            loader.load(new URLRequest("assets/config/rumpy.xml"));
        }

        private function onXMLComplete(evt:Event):void
        {
            var xmlData:XML = XML((evt.currentTarget as URLLoader).data);
            columnList = xmlData.Column;

            var cols:Array = list.columns;

            for each (var item:XML in columnList)
            {
                var adgc:AdvancedDataGridColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn(item.@dataField);
                adgc.headerText = item.@headerText;

                cols.push(adgc);    
            }

            list.columns = cols;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="list" x="10" y="10" dataProvider="{data}" width="360" height="120">
    <mx:columns/>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

</s:Application>
```

//rumpy.xml

```
<Columns>
        <Column id="first_name" headerText="First Name"     dataField="first_name"/>
        <Column id="regionName" headerText="Region"         dataField="region_name"/> 
        <Column id="lastname"   headerText="Last Name"      dataField="last_name"/>
</Columns>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this xml file is external i do nt want to declare in my code .....above i mention that my file is in  in assets/config/rumpy.xml from which i want to retrieve column name using header field.

Comment: In this case one just needs to load the XML before configurating the columns. I have edited my code.

Comment: If you use XML you have to options how to save information. You can create for each information part a new node in <> brackes or you can add new properties inside of the existing node's brackes. In your case you use the second approach. So to read the value you use the node's name and the @propertyName. In the code there is a cycle for each node of your XML. Each node is available as "item" variable. To access the property "headerText" you write item.@headerText. On the Internet there are a lot of explanations for this issue.